# a theorem about regularization of function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Theorem:

Let $u(x)$ is locally integrable function on $R^n$, 
 $\phi= e^{\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}}, when |x|<1;\phi= 0, when |x|\geq 1  $

$\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{C}\phi$
where $C=\int_{R^n}\phi(x)dx$

and $\alpha_{\epsilon}(x)=\frac{1}{{\epsilon}^n}\alpha(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$

then $u_\epsilon(x)=\int_{R^n}u(x-y)a_\epsilon(y)dy$ is a $C^\infty$ function.

The proof is so brief:

$a_\epsilon$ is a infinite continues differentiable function, so use the interchangeabilty of $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\int$, we can have $u_\epsilon(x)=\int_{R^n}u(x-y)a_\epsilon(y)dy$ is a $C^\infty$ function.

I'm still don't know how to proof it. 
can you give me a step-by-step proof? thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a convolution product.

Comment: And you need more hypothesis on $a_\epsilon$ for $u_\epsilon$ to be defined. Is $a_\epsilon$ a compactly supported function ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I've added those definitions in.

Comment: yes, according to definition of $a_\epsilon(x)$, it's support is $\{x: |x|<\epsilon\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$, we will try to prove that 
$(u * a_\epsilon)'(x)=u * a_\epsilon'(x).$

To begin, let $h>0$ :

$$\frac{u * a_\epsilon(x+h)-u * a_\epsilon(x)}h=\frac 1 h \int_{R^n}u(y)a_\epsilon(x+h-y)dy-\frac 1 h \int_{R^n}u(y)a_\epsilon(x-y)dy$$

By linearity of the integral :

$$\frac{u * a_\epsilon(x+h)-u * a_\epsilon(x)}h=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y) \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h)- a_\epsilon(x) \right] dy.$$

Hence :

$$\lim _{ h \to 0 } \frac{u * a_\epsilon(x+h)-u * a_\epsilon(x)}h = \lim _{ h \to 0 } \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y) \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right] dy.$$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then : $\forall 0<h<1, \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right]$ is compactly supported in some $K_{x,\epsilon}$. Hence :

$$\lim _{ h \to 0 } \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y) \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right]dy= \lim _{ h \to 0 } \int_{K_{x,\epsilon}}u(y) \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right]dy.$$

Now, we have, by some famous inequality, since $a_\epsilon \in C^1$ and has its support in $K_{x,\epsilon}$ being compact :

$$\left| a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right| \le \| a_\epsilon'\|_\infty h.$$

In other words :

$$\left|u(y) \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right] \right| \le \| a_\epsilon'\|_\infty\left|u(y)\right|.$$

Since $u$ is locally integrable : $\| a_\epsilon'\|_\infty\left|u(y)\right| \in L^1(K_{x,\epsilon})$, then we can, by dominated convergence theorem, exchange $\lim$ and $\int$ :

$$\lim _{ h \to 0 } \frac{u * a_\epsilon(x+h)-u * a_\epsilon(x)}h =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y) \lim _{ h \to 0 } \frac 1 h\left[ a_\epsilon(x+h-y)- a_\epsilon(x-y) \right] dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(y) a_\epsilon'(x-y) dy.$$

The right term exists and is well defined, then, if $a_\epsilon \in C^1$  :

$$(u * a_\epsilon)'(x)=u * a_\epsilon'(x).$$

Since $a_\epsilon \in C^\infty$, we have, by induction, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ :

$$(u * a_\epsilon)^{(n)}(x)=u * a_\epsilon^{(n)}(x).$$

Since $x$ is arbitrary, $u * a_\epsilon \in C^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you!  I think the second formula can be deleted. Am I right ?

Comment: They all seem important to me to make the path clear.

Comment: It seems haven't been used in the following path..

Comment: It seems haven't been used in the following path..

Comment: Then may be I do not understand which formula you are talking about.

Comment: I've mentioned about $

u∗a_\epsilon(x+h)−u∗a_\epsilon(x)h=\int_{R^n}{u(y)\frac{1}{h}[a_\epsilon(x+h)−a_\epsilon(x)]}dy.
$  Thanks !:)

Comment: May be the step was obvious, but I think it helps understanding the whole process.

Comment: understand! thank you for your reply :)